# Planar kelvin problem

Tags: geometry, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, tiling, geometric-topology

What is the minimal possible value of the maximal total side length shared by any two tiles in a tiling of the plane if all tiles have the same area $A$?

$\text{Total side length} = \text{Length-integral of the curve formed by the intersection of two tiles}$

i) Using a finite set of tiles
ii) Using any set of tiles.

This is known for $3D$ as http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KelvinsConjecture.html
I have found no info on the planar case, so it may be trivial, in which case I want to see the proof.

Comment: I fail to see how this has anything to do with elementary set theory...

Comment: My guess: hexagonal tiling.

Answer (score 4):

0 if each of the tiles is the fractal made by a hexagon with triangles on triangles on triangles which stick out on three sides and stick in on the other 3, like in the picture below. 
![tile][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1sW5.png

If by maximal sidelength you mean the maximum total sidelength rather than the maximum of any one side, then I suspect that a hexagonal tiling is the optimum, which has maximal side length $\sqrt{\frac{2A}{3\sqrt{3}}}$.

Comment: I think you got the maximal side length wrong.  If the side of the hexagon is $s$, the area is $A = 3\sqrt{3}s^2/2$, so the maximal sidelength is $\sqrt{2A/3\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks craig for pointing that out. The boundary between any two tiles must be a straight line, the shortest length connecting the two endpoints of the boundary curve.